# Creating flow velocity map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping, speed

I want to make velocity map in this format. I have points with vector attributes (u, v and velocity), but my arrows have only heads!

[image]

Comment: The length of the arrows is controlled by a field in the point layer. Make sure the scale of the values in that field are consistent with the units for the arrow length. If your values are less than the size of your arrow head, the arrow head will hide the rest of the arrow.